# Download file from the internet, HttpSendRequest fails with error code

Tags: c++, windows

I'm creating a program that can download files from the internet.
Before i download the file, i want to get the file size, and i have tried InternetQueryDataAvailable, but it gives a value of 0.

Then i tried hHttpRequest, but it gives error code ERROR_HTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND. So i added HttpSendRequest, but its giving error code ERROR_INTERNET_INVALID_URL.

I'm using the avg site as a test site:
http://free.avg.com/us-en/download-free-all-product

The file to be downloaded:
avg_free_x86_all_2014_4259a6848.exe

Any help would be nice, Thanks.

Code:

```
DWORD DownloadFile(PCHAR SaveDirectory)
{
HINTERNET hInternet;
CHAR StrBuffer[100];

hInternet = InternetOpen(InternetAgent, PRE_CONFIG_INTERNET_ACCESS, NULL, INTERNET_INVALID_PORT_NUMBER, 0);
if (hInternet != NULL)
{
    CHAR TestUrl[] = "http://download.avgfree.com/filedir/inst";
    CHAR TestFileName[] = "avg_free_x86_all_2014_4259a6848.exe";

    HINTERNET hHttpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, TestUrl, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
    if (hHttpSession != NULL)
    {
        PCTSTR AcceptTypes[] = {"text/*", "application/exe", "application/zlib", "application/gzip", "application/applefile", NULL};
        //I dont think application/exe is valid, but i could Not find a .exe format in the msdn list.
        //http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#application for the list

        HINTERNET hHttpRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hHttpSession, "GET", TestFileName, "HTTP/1.1", TestUrl, &AcceptTypes[0],
            INTERNET_FLAG_EXISTING_CONNECT|INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD|INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE, 0);

        if (hHttpRequest != NULL)
        {
            DWORD FileSize = 0;
            DWORD BufferLength = sizeof(FileSize);

            if (HttpSendRequest(hHttpRequest, NULL, 0, NULL, 0))
            {
                //See if HttpQueryInfo can get the file size.
                if (HttpQueryInfo(hHttpRequest, HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH, &FileSize, &BufferLength, NULL))
                {
                    sprintf_s(StrBuffer, sizeof(StrBuffer), "%u", FileSize);
                    MessageBox(MainWinHwnd, StrBuffer, "File Size", MB_OK);
                }
                else MessageBox(MainWinHwnd, "Failed to get the file size.", NULL, MB_OK);

                //See if InternetQueryDataAvailable can get the file size.
                if (InternetQueryDataAvailable(hHttpRequest, &FileSize, 0, 0))
                {
                    sprintf_s(StrBuffer, sizeof(StrBuffer), "%u", FileSize);
                    MessageBox(MainWinHwnd, StrBuffer, "File Size", MB_OK);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox(MainWinHwnd, "Failed to get the file size.", NULL, MB_OK);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DWORD LastError = GetLastError();
                sprintf_s(StrBuffer, sizeof(StrBuffer), "%u", LastError);
                MessageBox(NULL, StrBuffer, NULL, MB_OK);
            }
            InternetCloseHandle(hHttpRequest);
        }
        else MessageBox(NULL, "Error #3", NULL, MB_OK);
        InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession);
    }
    else MessageBox(NULL, "Error #2", NULL, MB_OK);
    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
}
else MessageBox(NULL, "Error #1", NULL, MB_OK);

return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling `InternetConnect()`, specify just `"download.avgfree.com"` by itself for the hostname, not a URL.

When calling `HttpOpenRequest()`, specify `"/filedir/inst/avg_free_x86_all_2014_4259a6848.exe"` as the object to request, not the filename by itself.

Use [`InternetCrackUrl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384376%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to divide a full URL into its individual components, passing the `lpszHostName` and `nPort` fields to `InternetConnect()` and the `lpszUrlPath` field to `HttpOpenRequest()`.

You also do not need to know the file size in order to download.  In fact, there will be times when no file size is known when the download begins. Sometimes there will be.  Either way, you can simply call `InternetReadFile()` in a loop until it reports that there is no more data to receive.  Let it handle the file size internally for you.

BTW, have a look at the [`URLDownloadToFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.  Let it handle these details for you.

Comment: Thanks for your fast and great answer. For anyone who uses HttpQueryInfo to get the file size, be sure to include the HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER flag.